# Vue Js Multiple Components Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've this component in a vue application

```
<b>Field Picker 1</b>
<field-picker
   :module="myModule"
   :fields="options.fields"
/>
```

in the same vue file, i've to declare it twice so the result will be

```
<b>Field Picker 1</b>
<field-picker
   :module="myModule"
   :fields="options.fields"
/>

<b>Field Picker 2</b>
<field-picker
   :module="myModule"
   :fields="options.fields"
/>
```

In order to modify :fields props itself i $emit an event like that (inside the field picker itself) :

`this.$emit('update:fields', f)`

My issue is that if i modify the first component (Field Picker 1) i'll retrive the same modifications on second component (Field Picker 2) because the $emit

this is the component (**FieldPicker.vue**)

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="fields d-flex">
        <div class="available">
          <label>{{ $t('field.selector.available') }}</label>
          <b-button @click.prevent="selectedFields = [...allFields]" variant="link" class="float-right">{{ $t('field.selector.selectAll') }}</b-button>
          <draggable
            class="drag-area border"
            :list.sync="availableFields"
            :group="group"
          >
            <div v-for="field in availableFields"
                 @dblclick="selectedFields = [field, ...selectedFields]"
                 class="field"
                 :key="field.name">
              <span v-if="field.label">{{ field.label }} ({{field.name}})</span>
              <span v-else>{{field.name}}</span>
              <span v-if="field.isRequired">*</span>
              <span class="system float-right" v-if="field.isSystem">{{ $t('field.selector.systemField') }}</span>
            </div>
          </draggable>
        </div>
        <div class="selected">
          <label>{{ $t('field.selector.selected') }}</label>
          <b-button @click.prevent="selectedFields = []" variant="link" class="float-right">{{ $t('field.selector.unselectAll') }}</b-button>
          <draggable
            class="drag-area border"
            v-model="selectedFields"
            :group="group"
          >
            <div v-for="(field) in selectedFields"
                 @dblclick="selectedFields = selectedFields.filter(({ name }) => field.name !== name)"
                 class="field"
                 :key="field.name">
              <span v-if="field.label">{{ field.label }} ({{field.name}})</span>
              <span v-else>{{field.name}}</span>
              <span v-if="field.isRequired">*</span>
              <span class="system float-right" v-if="field.isSystem">{{ $t('field.selector.systemField') }}</span>
            </div>
          </draggable>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i>{{ $t('field.selector.footnote') }}</i>
    </fieldset>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },

  props: {
    module: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    fields: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },

    disabledTypes: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },

    disableSystemFields: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    systemFields: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },

    fieldSubset: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },

    group: {
      type: String,
      default: 'fields',
    },
  },

  data () {
    return {
      modules: [],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    selectedFields: {
      get () {
        // Needs to be done this way so it retains order of fields
        return this.fields.reduce((fields, field) => {
          field = this.allFields.find(({ name }) => name === field.name)
          if (field) {
            fields.push(field)
          }
          return fields
        }, [])
      },

      set (f) {
        this.$emit('update:fields', f)
      },
    },

    allFields () {
      let mFields = []
      if (this.fieldSubset) {
        mFields = this.module.filterFields(this.fieldSubset)
      } else {
        mFields = this.module.fields
      }

      if (this.disabledTypes.length > 0) {
        mFields = mFields.filter(({ kind }) => !this.disabledTypes.find(t => t === kind))
      }

      let sysFields = []
      if (!this.disableSystemFields) {
        sysFields = this.module.systemFields()
        if (this.systemFields) {
          sysFields = sysFields.filter(({ name }) => this.systemFields.find(sf => sf === name))
        }
      } else {
        mFields = mFields.filter(({ isSystem }) => !isSystem)
      }

      return [
        ...[...mFields].sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label)),
        ...sysFields,
      ]
    },

    availableFields () {
      // Remove selected fields
      return this.allFields.filter(a => !this.fields.some(f => a.name === f.name))
    },
  },

  watch: {
    'moduleID' (o, n) {
      if (o !== n) {
        this.selectedFields = []
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
div.fields {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  .selected .field {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .available .field {
    cursor: e-resize;
  }

  & > div {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    clear: both;

    button.btn-link {
      font-size: 90%;
    }

    .drag-area {
      height: 150px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      padding: 2px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    span.system {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Do you know if there is any workaround that i can use in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code for actual component, and the code that receives and update data on event. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a different option.property like :

field picker 1 => option.fields
field picker 2 => option.fieldsSupplement

Comment: why ? :) if you can explain me (with the little amout of code that i've shared)

Comment: Brute forcing a solution by making that kind of change is not scalable. Imagine if you need to have 1000 field pickers, would you create 1000 different fields? Each component should have his own props and they should be separated without relying on a different object name.

Comment: yep yep you're right...almost sure the number won't increase..
but do you know if there is a different better approach in order to solve this ? (based on your advice)

Comment: Give us more details as TJ suggested. Then, we will be able to help you achieve a better solution.

Comment: i've shared the component too if you'd like to take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231694/discussion-between-dack-funk-and-kissu).